# How undo setState if Fecth was failed?

Tags: reactjs

Im trying change state and if internet connection lost. Component renders new state, but it doesn't changed on server. How i can undo last `setState` to prevent `state` change?

```
const Position = ({ value }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(value)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const { position } = await changePosition(position)
        setPosition(position)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [position])

  return (
    <Select
      value={position}
      onChange={(value) => setPosition(value)}
    >
     <Option value="left">Left</Option>
      <Option value="top">Top</Option>
      <Option value="right">Right</Option>
      <Option value="bottom">Bottom</Option>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what `changePosition()` does, but if it encounters an error and throws it, then your `catch` statement will be in effect and it will never continue to the `setPosition(position)` line. So it's not clear what you mean by "undoing" setState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useRef` hook to save previous position, for example:

```js
const Position = ({ value }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(value)
  // useRef here
  const prevPosition = useRef(position)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const { position } = await changePosition(position)
        // if success save new position and do something you want.
        prevPostion.current = position
        
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        // if fail setState to previous position.
        setPosition(prevPosition)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [position])

  return (
    <Select
      value={position}
      onChange={(value) => setPosition(value)}
    >
     <Option value="left">Left</Option>
      <Option value="top">Top</Option>
      <Option value="right">Right</Option>
      <Option value="bottom">Bottom</Option>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Hope to help you !

Comment: faced with problem that now i have two calls when have network error. because `useEffect` dependency changed two times. How fix that?

Comment: I edited the post, if it still doesn't solve your problem, I think it should be a different problem, you should create another post with your code to make the problem clearer.
I will help you if I have time :) , or other people will too !